# Parameter for Ecommerce Transaction timestamp in google measurment protocol?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, measurement-protocol

I am migrating pushing the e-commerce transactions from controller, to a cron job, that will run every minute.

However, I cannot seem to find the parameter in measurement protocol, which I could to specify the exact time at which the transaction occurred?

Anyone have any ideas? Is this even necessary, since the maximum delay will be 1 minute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot specify a timestamp for the transaction (you can add a custom dimension with a timestamp, but GA will happily ignore this for session aggregation).

What you can do is add an offset in milliseconds between the actual transaction time (or time of any other hit) and the time you finally send the hit to Google. This is called "[queue time](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#qt)", I think this was originally intended for native/web apps that might be offline for some time.

Just for a minute delay I probably would not bother. However it might be useful for cases when your cron job fails for some reason, and you want to pick up and send the transactions later.

Comment: The "qt" parameter for Queue Time (milliseconds since transaction actually occurred) can be up to 4 hours old.  See docs:  https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#qt

Comment: @phil_scott_a_person, Philip Walton (a Google engineer who works on Analytics) once mentioned in a comment that queue time works _reliably_ for four hours (which is why this is the value in the documentation) but that it might work for much longer (up to 24 hours - this is somehow connected to the way GA processes data after the session rollover at midnight). This is mostly a fun fact - I agree that for any practical purpose one should stick to the documentation.